# Lightning component (framework) error ("no such property") and "init" handler not invoked in a Lightning Component but not in Lightning Page tab. Why?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, flexipages

I have encountered a very strange behavior in my Lightning component and i cannot figure out why this error occurs and how to fix it - any help would be appreciated.

First my (simplified) component code (API 44):

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">

    <aura:attribute name="reservation" type="Object" default="{ customer: {}, lineItems: [] }" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>

    <h1>Hello {!v.reservation.customer.lastName}</h1>
    <p>You have {!v.reservation.lineItems.length} {!if(v.reservation.lineItems.length == 1, 'item', 'items')} in your reservation!</p>
    <lightning:button class="btn" label="{!if(empty(v.reservation.customer.id) &amp;&amp; not(empty(v.reservation.customer.lastname)), 'Edit', 'New')}" onclick="{!c.onCustomerButton}" />
</aura:component>
```

And the controller.js:

```
({
    init : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.reservation', {
            customer: {
                lastName: 'Smith'
            },
            lineItems: [
                { name: 'Item #1' }
            ]
        });
    },
    onCustomerButton : function(component, event, helper) { }
})
```

When I add this component to my navigation via a *Lightning **Component** Tab*, I get the following error when I access the tab:

> aura://ComponentController:
>   org.auraframework.throwable.AuraExecutionException:
>   org.auraframework.impl.root.component.IfProvider:
>   org.auraframework.throwable.AuraRuntimeException: no such property:
>   customer

Stack Trace:

> org.auraframework.throwable.AuraExecutionException:
>   aura://ComponentController:
>   org.auraframework.throwable.AuraExecutionException:
>   org.auraframework.impl.root.component.IfProvider:
>   org.auraframework.throwable.AuraRuntimeException: no such property:
>   customer  at .(markup://aura:if:1)    at .(markup://c:MyContainer.$:1)
>     at .(markup://aura:component.body[2]:1)     at
>   .(markup://lightning:button.$:1)  at
>   .(markup://aura:component.body[0]:1)  at
>   .(markup://aura:html.body[1](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000jhaFAAQ&title=lightning-aura-if-component-causes-internal-error-if-istrue-expression-accesses-an-attribute-with-type-object):1)   at .(aura://ComponentController)    at
>
> *[snip - Java Stack following]*

What is most confusing is, that the *init* method of my controller is **not** invoked before the error is thrown (i.e. my Chrome Dev Console breakpoint in that method is not being hit).

If instead of adding the component via *force:appHostable* using a *Lightning Component* tab, I implement the *flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes* interface and add the component via a Flexipage and a *Lightning Page Tab* it loads perfectly fine.
Unfortunately that is not a viable solution, since the page tabs suffer from some other downsides so I need to get the component tab up and running.

Does anyone have any clue about how to approach this (or point out what I'm doing wrong)?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:** Simply creating another "outer" component with the force:appHostable interface and include the one from above won't change anything - the same error message appears...

**EDIT 2:** Upon further investigation it seems as I've run into [this known and un-fixed issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000jhaFAAQ&title=lightning-aura-if-component-causes-internal-error-if-istrue-expression-accesses-an-attribute-with-type-object). Very frustrating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a Map instead of an Object. When you use Object, the `default` value is parsed as a String, thus causing the error you see.

```
<aura:attribute name="reservation" type="Map" default="{ customer: {}, lineItems: [] }" />
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. Did NOT find that in the documentation. I wonder why it behaves differently when viewed through a flexipage or through a lightning component tab though....

Comment: @Christoph It depends on what does the parsing, some components and attributes have their own rules. It is usually safest to use the correct type (e.g. Map) with aura:attribute default values to avoid parsing problems.

Answer (score 0):

`<aura:attribute name="reservation" type="Object" default="{ customer: {}, lineItems: [] }" />`

I believe object keys need to be in single quotes in the markup, like so...

`default="{ 'customer': {}, 'lineItems': [] }"`